# How to set/detect/remove a global flag in memory which can be seen by other processes?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

In Delphi XE2, how can I set a specific global flag in memory which can be seen by other processes and which is not removed when the process which created the global flag terminates. For example:

1) ProcessA:

```
if CreateGlobalFlag('{B244A213-72EC-47BF-814B-2E7608F55C50}') then
  MessageDialog('GlobalFlag has been created');
```

2) ProcessA terminates.

3) ProcessB:

```
boolGlobalFlagExists := IsGlobalFlagSet('{B244A213-72EC-47BF-814B-2E7608F55C50}');
if boolGlobalFlagExists then 
begin
  if RemoveGlobalFlag('{B244A213-72EC-47BF-814B-2E7608F55C50}') then
    MessageDialog('GlobalFlag has been removed');
end;
```

Other processes which don't know the above GUID should not be able to detect this global flag.

How can such a functionality be implemented?

EDIT201406231757:
The global flag should live in memory, if possible.
The flag should live until Windows shutdown, if possible.
The global flag should be per machine (not per user), if possible.
The global flag should die at ShutDown.
The global flag should be secret, if possible.

Comment: Create an empty file with this name in a common folder; or registry key with this name; a lot of solutions are possible.

Comment: Where do you want the flag to live? What is to be its lifetime? Forever. Until the other process shuts. Is it per user or per machine? Does it die when the user logs out? Shuts down?

Comment: Where do you want the flag to live? In memory, if possible. - What is to be its lifetime? Until Windows shut down, if possible. - Is it per user or per machine? Per machine, if possible. It dies at ShutDown.

Comment: @user246408 The global flag should be secret. Files in common folder can be detected.

Comment: It won't be secret. If the other program can read it, then so can somebody else. I don't see how you are going to keep it in memory, and off the disk, if you let process A terminate before process B starts. Perhaps you need process C to run all the time and act as the go between. Is there any scope for you to modify your design, or have you already decided on it and are inflexible to change.

Comment: In any case, the question needs to contain all the information that you offered in comments. Please can you edit it so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've played with atoms a little before noticed that the question was answered:

```
program TestAtoms;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows;

const
  AtomName = 'bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla';

var
  AtomValue: TAtom;

procedure Test;
begin
  AtomValue:= GlobalFindAtom(PChar(AtomName));
  if AtomValue = 0 then begin
    Writeln('Atom not found, creating');
    AtomValue:= GlobalAddAtom(PChar(AtomName));
    if AtomValue <> 0 then
      Writeln('Atom created, ', AtomValue)
    else
      Writeln('Atom create failed !!!');
  end
  else begin
    Writeln('Atom found, deleting');
    SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS);

    GlobalDeleteAtom(AtomValue);
    if GetLastError = ERROR_SUCCESS then
      Writeln('Atom deleted')
    else
      Writeln('Atom delete failed !!!');
  end;
end;

begin
  Test;
  Readln;
end.
```

---

**UPDATE**

Global Atom API is not secure; an adversary application can easily scan the global atom table and find your atom string:

```
procedure ScanAtomTable;
var
  nAtom: TAtom;
  Buffer: array[0..1023] of Char;
  Size: Cardinal;
  S: string;

begin
  nAtom:= $C000;
  repeat
    Size:= GlobalGetAtomName(nAtom, @Buffer, 1024);
    if Size > 0 then begin
      S:= PChar(@Buffer);
      Writeln(S);
    end;
    Inc(nAtom);
  until nAtom = 0;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated information. But what information could an attacker get from an anonymous GUID? Could he track it back to my application?

Comment: @user It's very hard for us to advise you on security without knowing your requirements.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did not ask user246408 to generally advise me, but rather specifically asked him whether anybody could get from an Atom item back to the creator of the Atom item.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using the Atom table, you may be better off using a volatile registry key. See the documentation for [RegCreateKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The `REG_OPTION_VOLATILE` will create a key that is maintained only in memory and will be discarded when the associated registry hive is unloaded.

So, if you use `RegCreateKeyEx` to create a `REG_OPTION_VOLATILE` key in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` key, that key will stick around until the machine is shutdown.

If you really need to keep the content "secret", you can secure the registry key to ensure that only certain users or groups may read its content.

This should meet all of the requirements that you have laid out.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a global atom to persist an in-memory flag beyond a process's lifetime.

[About Atom Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649053.aspx):

> The atom name of a string atom remains in the global atom table as long as its reference count is greater than zero, **even after the application that placed it in the table terminates**.

For example:

```
if GlobalAddAtom('{B244A213-72EC-47BF-814B-2E7608F55C50}') <> 0 then
  MessageDialog('GlobalFlag has been created');
```

```
var
  GlobalFlag: ATOM;
begin
  GlobalFlag := GlobalFindAtom('{B244A213-72EC-47BF-814B-2E7608F55C50}');
  if GlobalFlag <> 0 then 
  begin
    SetLastError(0);
    GlobalDeleteAtom(GlobalFlag);
    if GetLastError() = 0 then
      MessageDialog('GlobalFlag has been removed');
  end;
```

Just keep in mind that the global atom table is a limited resource.  It can only hold less than 16K atoms at a time, and those atoms are used for other global resources, like registered clipboard formats.  So use atoms sparingly.

Also, unforeseen situations, like Explorer/session crashes, can wipe the global atom table, thus losing your flag.

Comment: Very many thanks to both Remy Lebeau and user246408 for this ATOM solution!!